# What are the two prongs on high voltage bushings?

Tags: high-voltage

I have noticed that some high voltage bushings mainly found on the high voltage side of transformers (eg 20kV) have two prongs spaced out like in the picture below.

[image: High voltage bushings].

One seems to be connected to the high voltage conductor and the other seems to be grounded. I believe it has to do something with high voltage discharges but I can not find any information on the matter. So what is the exact purpose of those prongs?

Comment: Looks like [Arcing Horns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcing_horns)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks that exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Protection against lightning, limits the voltage across the insulator if the line is hit